# center align a div with inline-block display

Tags: css, html

aligning a div that has width is very simple just setting left and right margin to auto will do the trick:

```
<div style="margin:0px auto;">
```

but in most cases as the content is dynamic, I can't set a width do the div, using the inline-block has the desired result for div's width but the center aligning doesn't work. anybody have any Idea how to center a div that its width is defined by its content width?

by the way, I want to know if it is possible to do such thing with css, not with jQuery or javascript.

Comment: give parent element `text-align: center`.

Comment: great. It did really worked. why didn't I thought of this :|. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Mr_Green If you wirte it as answer I can mark it as answer.

Comment: I think NOX did the same what I commented above :)

Comment: @Mr_Green I post the answer, and now I see this comment, post yours, I delete mine :)

Comment: @NOX dude, I don't hold any authority on it. It is alright. (ok posting it then).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give parent element `text-align: center`

For more info on text-align go through this [**link**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

Comment: @NOX actually your answer was the same with complete code but as Mr_Green was first to answer I want to give him the credit. Thank you too for answering.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; background: yellow">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

- Check the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qkh4v/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can shrink wrap the contents with the varying width.  You need two containing elements to do this, like so:

```
.outer-wrapper {
   float: right;
   position: relative;
   left: -50%;
}

.inner-wrapper {
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/te4es/